# Architecture for Live Audio Streaming web app

Tags: websocket, architecture, single-page-application, audio-streaming, http-streaming

Need your opinions on architecture for the live audio streaming app.

Currently, I'm testing it on a local network, and everything seems to work, but I have doubts about how good it will be in production.

My architecture:

```
                         1               2 
Broadcaster HTTP client ---> App Server ---> Listening clients (React.js App)
```

`1` — communication over HTTP, `2` — communication over HTTP and WebSocket

**What I want to do:**

1. When the user opens my React App and the Broadcaster is not streaming yet, React should display something like "OFFLINE"
2. Next, when the Broadcaster starts streaming to App Server, React App should display "The stream is started" and automatically start the playback.
3. Finally, when the Broadcaster stops streaming, React App should display "OFFLINE" again.

**How I currently do it:**
My App server uses two protocols: HTTP (for audio streaming and other stuff) and WebSocket (only for sending JSON status messages of what happens on the server).

1. When The Broadcaster starts streaming to the App Server (over HTTP), the App Server sends the WebSocket message to React App: "the stream has started, you can access it at `http://my-domain/stream` i.e. the App Servers streams the audio to React over regular HTTP.
2. React App sees this message and renders HTML `<audio>` element and starts playing the audio.
3. When the Broadcaster has stopped streaming, App Server sends WebSocket message to React App "the stream is finished" and React hides the player, displaying "OFFLINE"

So, I do all streaming (both from Broadcaster to App Server and from App Server to React client) over HTTP and use WebSocket to communicate real-time stream state updates.

How good is this architecture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How good is this architecture?

It's not so much a matter of good or bad, it's a matter of whether or not it's appropriate for your use case.  I'd note that this is basically exactly how internet radio servers such as SHOUTcast and Icecast have worked for 20+ years, so it can't be that bad.  :-)